# How to know if Activity is created by specific activity_alias

Tags: android

I have two aliases for same activity, alias 1 , alias 2, based on the alias information I want to do different stuff in an activity, Can I get to do this ?

Comment: "you can easily tell from the ActivityInfo retrieved via the PackageManager whether your app has been started from an alias or the original activity" via comment in http://stackoverflow.com/a/11244367/995891

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check activity alias into target activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36834858/check-activity-alias-into-target-activity)