# Check activity alias into target activity

Tags: android

I've got an activity called A. I want to add two activity-alias called B and C. Is it possible to know if A is called as B or C in the code? I want to apply a different behavior when it's called as B or C.

Comment: Do you mean when starting activity, you want to know what is it called ?

Comment: Yep, I'd like to know if A is called "from" B or C

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can provide some additional information to each `<actvity-alias>` in the `Manifest` and evaluate the `ActivityInfo` with the help of `PackageManager`:

To illustrate this, let's assume you want to display two `TextView`s in your target `Activity` and set the content depending on which alias is used.

In the `Manifest`, you put the following elements:

```
<activity
    android:name=".HalloActivity"
    android:label="@string/HalloDefault" >
</activity>
<activity-alias
    android:name=".SalutActivity"
    android:targetActivity=".HalloActivity"
    android:label="@string/SalutAlias">
    <meta-data android:name="LOCALE" android:value="fr" />
</activity-alias>
<activity-alias
    android:name=".HelloActivity"
    android:targetActivity=".HalloActivity"
    android:label="@string/HelloAlias">
    <meta-data android:name="LOCALE" android:value="en" />
</activity-alias>
```

To use an alias, start the `Activity` like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
String pName = getPackageName();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(pName, pName + ".HelloActivity");
intent.setComponent(componentName);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in then `onCreate()` method of **HalloActivity**, get the `android:label` and the `<meta-data>` like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hallo);

    String text;
    String label = "?";
    String locale = "de";
    int color;

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    try
    {
        ActivityInfo ai = pm.getActivityInfo(intent.getComponent(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

        label = getString(ai.labelRes);

        Bundle b = ai.metaData;

        if (b != null)
        {
            locale = b.getString("LOCALE");
            if (locale == null)
            {
                locale = "en";
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    }

    switch(locale)
    {
        case "en":
            text = "hello world :)";
            color = Color.BLUE;
            break;
        case "fr":
            text = "salut tout le monde :D";
            color = Color.RED;
            break;
        default:
            text = "hallo zusammen ;)";
            color = Color.GREEN;
    }


    TextView tvHello = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHello);
    tvHello.setText(text);
    tvHello.setTextColor(color);

    TextView tvLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLabel);
    tvLabel.setText(label);
}
```

Important when working with `<activity-alias>` (quoted from [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-alias-element.html)):

> With the exception of targetActivity,  attributes are a subset of activity attributes. For attributes in the subset, none of the values set for the target carry over to the alias. However, for attributes not in the subset, the values set for the target activity also apply to the alias.

Find out more about `<meta-data>` in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/meta-data-element.html).