# Android: run another app instead of requested

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, low-level

I write 2 applications for Android: A and B.
All seems OK, but my task is very specified.
It's not practical, it is learning low-level Android capabilities.

I need simple following: listen a LAUNCH intent of app A in app B or another way if you know.

**The result must be: when I press app A icon, app B must started.**

Not in onCreate! I know this method very well, but **not a single line of application code A should be executed**. Just run app B immediately.
I control both apps A and B, I write them. How I can do described?

Very similar [Two launchers for a single activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240023/two-launchers-for-a-single-activity), only I need to redirect alias to another application.

Comment: you have 2 different applications right?

Comment: yes, with different package names

Comment: This is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Apps are isolated so luckily you cannot do that otherwise that would be serious security risk.