# How to auto add app shortcut on android?

Tags: android

I tried , and if I delete shortcut then, on launch app shortcut is created

how to create application shortcut on android only on application install ?

Comment: By "launch" do you mean launching while developing using an IDE (like eclipse) or using command?

Answer (score 0):

May be you should see this post and its links from that post:

[How to create shortcut of android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217741/how-to-add-application-shortcuts-programitically-in-android)

I hope it will help you.