# How to set shortcuts on lock screen programmatically

Tags: java, android

I know how to set shortcuts on home-screen but not on lock-screen. Any ideas?

Comment: Please Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908774/android-launcher-shortcuts

Comment: that's not for lock-screen is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few, if any, Android devices have a lockscreen that supports shortcuts. I have over 50 devices, from all major manufacturers, and none support shortcuts on the lockscreen.

If you happen to have an Android device that does, contact the device manufacturer and ask if they have an API to allow third-party apps to put shortcuts on their lockscreen.