# Android: How to get my application's icon on lock screen

Tags: android, shortcut, lockscreen

I need to get a short cut launch for my application. So I need to provide the shortcut icon on the lock screen. How do I get this done?

Comment: [Did you mean app widgets?](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)

Comment: [How to set shortcuts on lock screen programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24384520/how-to-set-shortcuts-on-lock-screen-programmatically)

Comment: @Developer: Thanks a lot. Looks like its not possible in general.

Answer (score 0):

> As a user navigates through, out of, and back to your app, the
>   Activity instances in your app transition between different states in
>   their lifecycle. For instance, when your activity starts for the first
>   time, it comes to the foreground of the system and receives user
>   focus. During this process, the Android system calls a series of
>   lifecycle methods on the activity in which you set up the user
>   interface and other components. If the user performs an action that
>   starts another activity or switches to another app, the system calls
>   another set of lifecycle methods on your activity as it moves into the
>   background (where the activity is no longer visible, but the instance
>   and its state remains intact).

So, this is not possible due to maintain **App Life Cycle**.

You can check **[App Widgets](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)**